# Git using wrong user when pushing to remote URL

Tags: git, github

So I have an old GitHub account that I don't use anymore, but I'm still using the same laptop so all the old config files pointing to my old git user are still there.

So I went to `~/.gitconfig` and changed

```
[user]
        name = my_new_user
        email = my_new_user@email.com
```

however, whenever I'm in a project repo and I try to push I get this error

```
ERROR: Permission to my_new_user/gitrepo.git denied to my_old_user.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I've tried going into the local config file in my project. Changing the remote url from `http://github/my_new_user/gitrepo.git` to

```
url = git@github:my_new_user/gitrepo.git
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

I feel like I'm being stupid and missing something but I can't figure it out since the stuff I've already read suggest changing the remote origin url and mine doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: do you have a `pushurl` set? the `user.name` setting only affects the authorship of the commit, not access to the repository.

Comment: @gauteh ahh I see no I don't have a `pushurl` set. I have a `fetchurl` though. Which i'm assuming is my issue

Comment: You can use only `url`, if `pushurl` and `fetchurl` is equal and unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, incase someone comes across a similar issue here's what fixed it for me.

Within my local project `.git/` and in the `config` file I had the url `url = git@github:my_new_user/gitrepo.git`

Which didn't work, I changed this to `url = git@github.com-my_new_user:my_new_user/gitrepo_name`

I can push to my repo fine now. I think what @gauteh mentioned in the comments above may be a better way to go down by setting a `pushurl` but I couldn't get it to work and came across the above which worked for me.

Link to *changing git remote url article that I used for reference* https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/